# Counting the Number of Palindromes in a Sentence

Tags: c++, function, pointers, palindrome

Good day, everyone! Below is a program which asks a user for a sentence and outputs the number of palindromes in it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome (const std::string& s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (s.length())/2; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != s[s.length()-1 - i])
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}


int main() {
    string sentence;
    int counter=0;
    cout << "Please input a sentence." << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    stringstream processtokens(sentence);
    for(string word; processtokens >> word;) 
        if(isPalindrome(word)) 
            ++counter;
    cout << "Number of Palindromes are : " << counter << endl;
}
```

It works just fine. But for example, when I input "The quick brown gag has a blue eye.", the number of palindromes the program displays is just 1 but in reality, the sentence has 2 palindromes: gag and eye. The problem is that the word "eye" has a period. So how can the program ignore the period and other punctuation marks like comma when, for instance, the user entered "I love noon, evening, and midnight". Noon is a palindrome but the program doesn't recognize it because of the comma.

Another problem is the capitalization. I want this program to work (and ignore ASCII equivalents) when the user entered "Madam, my work is done." I know it has something to do with *tolower*.

To summarize, I want this program to have a **function** which a) **ignores punctuations marks** and b) **capitalization**.

And oh, what is the alternative for " stringstream processtokens(sentence);... "? Rather that, I need this program to use **substring (substr) and find**.

Please guide me, guys! Thank you and any kind of help is very appreciated. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: You already described pretty much everything you need to do. Convert everything to lower-case as you go along, and skip over non-letters. You're almost there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ispunct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/ispunct/) and ignore any characters where ispunct returns true. You should also wrap your character comparisons in calls [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/)()

Comment: Just wondering but, does tolower() throw an exception when it encounters a number? Or does it just move on?

Comment: @Farhad: When it encounters a number, the value returned is unchanged.

Comment: @Oleksi: Thank you! But how do I ignore them? I've done the bool function but I don't know what to do next to "ignore" those characters. Please and thank you!

Comment: @CandaceParker- You can use the `std::remove_if` algorithm to remove all punctuation characters from the input string: `string.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), ::to_lower), string.end()).`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this little exercise can be used to introduce some nice C++ features such as iterators:

```
inline bool is_letter(char c)
{ return ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'); }


bool is_palindrome(const std::string & s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator rt = s.rbegin();

    while (it != s.end() && rt != s.rend() && std::distance(it, rt.base()) > 0)
    {
        // Skip non-letters
        while (it != s.end() && !is_letter(*it)) { ++it; }
        while (rt != s.rend() && !is_letter(*rt)) { ++rt; }

        if (it == s.end() || rt == s.rend()) { break; }

        // Check palindromy
        if (std::tolower(*it) != std::tolower(*rt)) { return false; }

        // Move on
        ++it;
        ++rt;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The trick is to attack the string from both ends. For this, we have an ordinary iterator, `it`, coming from the beginning of the string, and a *reverse* iterator, `rt`, coming from the end of the string.

The heart of the code is the check for palindromy (case insensitively, by comparing downcased characters), and immediate `return false` in the even of failure; otherwise the two iterators are advanced by one.

Finally, the beginning of the loop gobbles up non-letter characters from the string, so those are flat-out ignored. We check again whether we reached the end of the string after gobbling; you must make sure that you only dereference an iterator to a valid element!

The loop stops when the forward-moving iterator has gone past the backward-moving one. This is the content of the condition `distance(it, rt.base()) > 0`: the "base" of the reverse iterator is actually an ordinary iterator to the element *after* the reverse-iterator's   element. So `it` hasn't crossed over `rt` as long as the distance from `it` to the base of `rt` is strictly greater than zero. (The distance is precisely 1 when `it` and `rt` refer to the same element.)

Comment: Thank you very much! You are of great help! However, when I ran the program and entered "Hello noon, I love you!", it displayed 2 as the number of palindromes. I'm wondering why is that so...

Even so. I'm very grateful because you explained those to me clearly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I stand corrected. "I" is a palindrome itself! Thank you again! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a function to check for punctuation. You might want to try `ispunct`